# fill an HashMap with elements of a set passed as parameter

Tags: java, unit-testing, hashmap, hashset

i have to write the method:

```
    public Map<Robot, Integer> PickedUpForEachRobot(Set<Stuff> pickedUp)
```

which has to iterate through the set passed as parameter and has to count the quantity of stuff picked up by each robot and associate it to his instance.

what i have done is this:

```
public Map<Robot, Integer> PickedUpForEachRobot(Set<Stuff> pickedUp) {
    final Map<Robot,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for(Stuff stuff : pickedUp){
        Integer quantity = map.get(stuff.getPicker());
        if(quantity!=null){
            map.put(stuff.getPicker(), quantity);
        }
    }
    return map;

}
```

I also have other classes:

```
public class Stuff {

private Robot picker;

public Robot getPicker() {
    return this.picker;
}
```

}

and:

```
public class Robot {

private Set<Stuff> bunchOfStuff;

public Set<Stuff> getBunchOfStuff() {
    return this.bunchOfStuff;
}
```

}

for which i have tried to be synthetic, so i hope i can be clear anyway.

So my problem is that when i do a test for this method:

```
@Test
public void testRaccoltoPerMezzo() {
    Statistics stats = new Statistics();
    Stuff stuff1 = new ball();
    Stuff stuff2 = new legoPiece();
    Set<Stuff> set = new HashSet<>();
    set.add(stuff1);
    assertEquals(1,set.size());
    Map<Robot,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(stuff1.getPicker(),1);

    assertEquals(map, stats.PickedUpForEachRobot(set));

}
```

it fails and it says to me:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<{null=1}> but was:<{}>
```

and i can't understand why. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1):

This message :

> java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<{null=1}> but was:<{}>

means that you expect to have a map with one element that owns a `null` key and as  associated value `1` but you got a empty map.

The expected map you have created doesn't seem to be adequate according to your requirement and the actual map either.
About the populating of the map in the implementation, I noticed at least this point that is not at all logical.

Here :

```
final Map<Robot,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
for(Stuff stuff : pickedUp){
    Integer quantity = map.get(stuff.getPicker());
    if(quantity!=null){
        map.put(stuff.getPicker(), quantity);
    }
}
```

`Integer quantity = map.get(stuff.getPicker());` will always value quantity to `null` as you get it from an empty map : `map = new HashMap<>();` and you populate the map only if quantity is not `null` :

```
if(quantity!=null){
      map.put(stuff.getPicker(), quantity);
 }
```

But it will never happen as the map is empty : so you never populate the map.

You have probably other issues in the code but I hope it will help you to rework your logic.

Comment: First of all thank's for your answer. Do you have any idea on how to solve this kind of situation? I ask it beacause i already knew that that line is always returning null, but i have been stucking on this method for too long trying to solve this issue

Comment: You are welcome. I am not sure to understand your need. I think that in PickedUpForEachRobot(), the idea is to iterate on the Set of Stuff and to get the quantity of the picker. Then update the map with this quantity. But the problem is that I don't see the quantity in your model.

Comment: do you think it is possible that the problem is that i have to fill the set passed as parameter with Stuff elements? Because when i do stuff.getPicker() it always gives me null.